# Comparing an instance of a type param to null, even with no class constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

The following code compiles:

```
class Testing<TKey, TValue>
{
    public bool Test(TKey key)
    {
        return key == null;
    }
}
```

However, TKey can be a value type, and possibly not allow the value "null".

I know the results of this program, and how to add constraints.  What I'm wondering is **why doesn't the compiler disallow this when TKey is not constrained to "class"?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's convenient to be able to do this in various cases. If `TKey` is a non-nullable value type, the result of the comparison will always be false. (It's possible that the JITter will remove that branch entirely - don't forget that although one version of the JITted code is shared for all reference types, it reJITs for each value type.)

EDIT: One interesting use for this is precisely to allow `Nullable<T>` comparisons with null. `TFoo=Nullable<T>` doesn't satisfy *either* the `where TFoo : class` *or* `where TFoo : struct` constraints.

Comment: Since you won't get any notice when I reply to your comment to my answer, I'm posting here as well:  couldn't you assign to a different temp variable from default(T) and then compare to that?

Answer (score 1):

As for the "why", I'm not sure.  But to fix it, you can use `default(T)` instead of `null`.

Comment: Nope - you can't compare with default(T) using ==. The *only* value you can compare with is null.

Comment: Well, that depends if that is the purpose of the function.

His version...
var testing = new Testing<int, object>();
bool result = testing.Test(0); // false;

Your version...
var testing = new Testing<int, object>();
bool result = testing.Test(0); // true;

Comment: Couldn't you do an assigment to a different variable from default(T), and compare to that?

Comment: You can do assignments, but you can't do comparisons. I suspect that's to discourage people from thinkinh that an overloaded == will be called.

Comment: You can use Comparer<T>.Default though.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought about deleting this, but I'll leave it up in case someone else has the same confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Because it cast your variable to object and use object == operator
For a value type it's always false.

Answer (score 0):

because everything in csharp is an object.
in other words [Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the object class type.](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive75.html)
example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        struct SimpleStruct
        {
            int a;
            public SimpleStruct(int a)
            {
                this.a = a;
            }
        }
        enum SimpleEnum
        {
            a = 1,
            b = 2,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleStruct tp = new SimpleStruct(2);

            object ob = tp;
            if (ob != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("struct is an object : " + ob);
                tp = (SimpleStruct)ob;
            }

            SimpleEnum tp2 = SimpleEnum.a;
            ob = tp2;
            if (ob != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enum is an object : " + ob);
                tp2 = (SimpleEnum)ob;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he said he knows how to add constraints. he's wondering why the compiler will let you write "key == null" WITHOUT the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Because TKey could be nullable type.

Since C# 2.0 struct is comparable with null. That's why you can write 0 == null with no compile error.